# Hibernate joining extra table with manually specified HQL join

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, join

I'm specifying a join with HQL to fetch a single field from my `addresses` table, related to `users` through a linking table `users_addresses`. That works, but my problem is that Hibernate is also joining another linking tables `users_phoneNumbers`.

```
public Country getUserCountry(Integer userId) {
        return (Country) entityManager.createQuery("SELECT a.country FROM User u JOIN u.address a WHERE u.id = :userId")
                .setParameter("userId", userId).getSingleResult();
    }
```

And the query it executes:

```
Hibernate: 
    /* SELECT
        a.country 
    FROM
        User u 
    JOIN
        u.address a 
    WHERE
        u.id = :userId */ select
            address1_.country as col_0_0_ 
        from
            users user0_ 
        left outer join
            users_phoneNumbers user0_1_ 
                on user0_.id=user0_1_.userId_fk 
        left outer join
            users_addresses user0_2_ 
                on user0_.id=user0_2_.userId_fk 
        inner join
            addresses address1_ 
                on user0_2_.addressId=address1_.id 
        where
            user0_.id=?
```

My User object has some other fields that are relations to other tables, but is only extra joining to phone numbers.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 47483884837236327284854L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    private LocalDate birthDate;

    private Boolean notifications = TRUE;

    @OneToMany(fetch = EAGER, cascade = {ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private final Set<UserSkill> skills = new HashSet<>();

    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @OneToOne(fetch = EAGER, cascade = ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_phoneNumbers", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userId"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "phoneNumberId"))
    private PhoneNumber phoneNumber;

    @OneToOne(fetch = EAGER, cascade = ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_addresses", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userId"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "addressId"))
    private Address address;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = EAGER)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @CollectionTable(name = "users_userInterests", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userId"))
    @Column(name = "userInterest")
    private final Set<UserInterest> userInterests = new HashSet<>();

    private String profilePhoto;

    private LocalDateTime created;

    private User() {
    }

    public User(String name, LocalDate birthDate, Set<UserSkill> skills) {
        this.name = name;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
        this.skills.addAll(skills);
    }

    public void addSkills(Collection<UserSkill> skills) {
        this.skills.addAll(skills);
    }

    public void removeSkills(Collection<UserSkill> skills) {
        this.skills.removeAll(skills);
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        if (phoneNumber != null) {
            return phoneNumber.getPhoneNumber();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Boolean isPhoneNumberVerified() {
        if (phoneNumber != null) {
            return phoneNumber.getIsVerified();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I suspect that it might have something to do with the phoneNumber-related getters, but that's just an idea.

Why is this happening? How can I avoid it?

Comment: What's `@Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)`?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic That's a Lombok annotation. It means 'don't automatically generate a getter for this field'